# AllegroGraph Client HTTPException

Tags: java, semantic-web, allegrograph

I´m trying to import a *.nt File into AllegroGraph by using the AllegroGraph Client (version 4.1.1) on Windows. I use the AllegroGraph WebView application to start the server. First of all, I tried to create a connection, a catalog and a repository.
Upon creating a repository, my system throws an `com.franz.agraph.http.exception.AGHttpException`

This is my source-code:

```
package mytest;

public class NTLoader {

    public static String SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
    public static String CATALOG_ID = "";
    public static String REPOSITORY_ID = "test3";
    public static String USERNAME = "me";
    public static String PASSWORD = "xyzzy";
    public static String TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Tests getting the repository up. 
            System.out.println("\nStarting example.");
            AGServer server = new AGServer(SERVER_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println(server.getRootCatalog().getCatalogName());
            AGCatalog catalog = server.getCatalog(server.getRootCatalog().getCatalogName());
            AGRepository myRepository = catalog.createRepository(REPOSITORY_ID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
```

Output:

```
Starting example().
/
org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: com.franz.agraph.http.exception.AGHttpException: An unexpected error occurred.
    at com.franz.agraph.repository.AGCatalog.createRepository(AGCatalog.java:240)
    at com.franz.agraph.repository.AGCatalog.createRepository(AGCatalog.java:211)
    at mytest.NTLoader.main(NTLoader.java:86)
Caused by: com.franz.agraph.http.exception.AGHttpException: An unexpected error occurred.
    at com.franz.agraph.http.handler.AGErrorHandler.newException(AGErrorHandler.java:70)
    at com.franz.agraph.http.handler.AGErrorHandler.handleResponse(AGErrorHandler.java:47)
    at com.franz.agraph.http.AGHTTPClient.get(AGHTTPClient.java:180)
    at com.franz.agraph.http.AGHTTPClient.getTupleQueryResult(AGHTTPClient.java:376)
    at com.franz.agraph.repository.AGCatalog.listRepositories(AGCatalog.java:173)
    at com.franz.agraph.repository.AGCatalog.hasRepository(AGCatalog.java:193)
    at com.franz.agraph.repository.AGCatalog.createRepository(AGCatalog.java:235)
    ... 2 more
```

Line 86 is

```
AGRepository myRepository = catalog.createRepository(REPOSITORY_ID);
```

How I run it:
1) Run agwebview.exe --port 8080
2) Wait for the server to be started
3) Run Java-Class
I´ve already searched fo a solution with google, and looked into the javadoc of the createRepository() command, but couldnt find any solution. What could cause this behaviour and how can I fix it ?
My OS is Windows 7 SP 1 and the java-class runs with JDK 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by switching over to Linux and using the most recent AGWebView version. Afterwards I figured out, that Ive initially used the client of AG 4 for an AG 3.3 Server.

**For anyone else who encounters this problem:**
Make sure you use the right JAR-files